# TSQL Query to combine all records after first full record displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hey all here is my issue.

My query output looks like this (stripped down to a few rows):

```
|number |line |partNum |phoneNum     |qty_SN |qty_Property |qty_Name |qty_Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|87     |1    |55G5    |555-789-7512 |00123  |Local        |Owner    |05:22
|87     |     |        |             |14988  |Local        |Seller   |10:44
|87     |     |        |             |521    |Remote       |Owner    |01:05
|87     |     |        |             |50697  |Local        |Seller   |11:41
|87     |     |        |             |2359   |Remote       |Seller   |04:45
```

And what I am looking to want to do is this:

```
|number |line |partNum |phoneNum     |qty_SN                     |qty_Property                    |qty_Name                         |qty_Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|87     |1    |55G5    |555-789-7512 |00123,14988,521,50697,2359 |Local,Local,Remote,Local,Remote |Owner,Seller,Owner,Seller,Seller |05:22,10:44,01:05,11:41,04:45
```

Notice that all the **qty_** columns are combined into the **first** full data row instead of being on their own row like in the first table.

The query for the first table looks like this (again, stripped down):

```
;WITH TheDATA AS (
   SELECT 
      BL.number                                  AS 'number', 
      BL.line                                    AS 'line', 
      BL.partNumber                              AS 'partNum',
      BL.phoneNumber                             AS 'phoneNum',
      L.qtySN                                    AS 'qty_SN',
      I.qtyProperty                              AS 'qty_Property',
      I.qtyName                                  AS 'qty_Name',
      I.qtyTime                                  AS 'qty_Time',
      ROW_NUMBER() Over (
         PARTITION BY 
             BL.number 
         ORDER BY
             BL.number
      )                                          AS 'RowNo'
   FROM
      BList                                      AS BL
   INNER JOIN Location                           AS L
      ON BL.ID                                    = L.Route
   INNER JOIN Inventory                          AS I
      ON L.ID                                     = I.prodID
   )
SELECT
   number                                        AS 'number',
   IIF(RowNo = 1, CONVERT(varchar, line), '')    AS 'line',
   IIF(RowNo = 1, partNumber, '')                AS 'partNum',
   IIF(RowNo = 1, phoneNumber, '')               AS 'phoneNum',
   qty_SN                                        AS 'qty_SN',
   qty_Property                                  AS 'qty_Property',
   qty_Name                                      AS 'qty_Name',
   qty_Time                                      AS 'qty_Time'
FROM
   TheData
```

Comment: your `TheDATA` CTE does not have column named `RowNo`, also there is no builtin function named `IFF()` in sql server

Comment: @avb Corrected **IFF** to **IIF** and **AS 'RowNo'**. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: You need 4 subqueries that use an ordered FOR XML against a set with a ROW_NUMBER to correctly order the results.

Comment: @StealthRT I don't see how that AS 'RowNo' fixed anything.

Comment: @paparazzo It didn't fix my current issue - it just corrected my mistake in writing the query I currently have that I accidently left out.

Comment: What does AS 'RowNo'  do?   It does not look like valid syntax to me.

Comment: @paparazzo It pretty much checks if its **not** the first row any longer then put a blank inside that cell.

Comment: @StealthRT I just tested on my server and it is not valid syntax.

Comment: @paparazzo Ah I see - made a mistake again. Corrected the OP.

Comment: You should not use string literal as your aliases. They are just ugly to look at and don't actually fit in the sql standard. https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases If you need another reason that style has been deprecated in 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017 And of course defining an alias that is the same name as the column is just a waste of effort. The concept of alias is lost there.

Comment: Tab semicolumns, my eyes bleed!

Comment: I give up. STILL not valid syntax.

Comment: Don't give up @paparazzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result query would look like this:

```
;WITH CTE(number, line, partNum, phoneNum, qty_SN, qty_Property, qty_Name, qty_Time)
AS
(
    SELECT 87     ,1       ,'55G5'   ,'555-789-7512'  ,00123  ,'Local'  ,'Owner'  ,'05:22' UNION ALL
    SELECT 87     ,null    ,null     ,null            ,14988  ,'Local'  ,'Seller' ,'10:44' UNION ALL
    SELECT 87     ,null    ,null     ,null            ,521    ,'Remote' ,'Owner'  ,'01:05' UNION ALL
    SELECT 87     ,null    ,null     ,null            ,50697  ,'Local'  ,'Seller' ,'11:41' UNION ALL
    SELECT 87     ,null    ,null     ,null            ,2359   ,'Remote' ,'Seller' ,'04:45'
)
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
   number                                        AS 'number',
   line                                          AS 'line',
   partNum                                       AS 'partNum',
   phoneNum                                      AS 'phoneNum',
   qty_SN = (
      Stuff(
           (
             SELECT + ', ' + 
                CAST(qty_SN AS Varchar(100))  
             FROM 
                CTE 
             FOR 
                XML PATH ('')
           ), 1, 1, ''
      )
   ),
   qty_Property = (
      Stuff(
           (
             SELECT + ', ' + 
                CAST(qty_Property AS Varchar(100))  
             FROM 
                CTE 
             FOR 
                XML PATH ('')
           ), 1, 1, ''
      )
   ),
   qty_Name = (
      Stuff(
           (
             SELECT + ', ' + 
                CAST(qty_Name AS Varchar(100))  
             FROM 
                CTE 
             FOR 
                XML PATH ('')
           ), 1, 1, ''
      )
   ),
   qty_Time = (
      Stuff(
           (
             SELECT + ', ' + 
                CAST(qty_Time AS Varchar(100))  
             FROM 
                CTE 
             FOR 
                XML PATH ('')
           ), 1, 1, ''
      )
   )
  FROM
   CTE 
  WHERE 
    partNum IS NOT null
) AS dt
```

Working [DEMO](http://%20http://rextester.com/NIZ64271)

Comment: A few notes, this will work when you have 1 set of data only, and the order of the comma delimited values isn't guaranteed without an appropiate Order By clause.

Comment: @EzLo yeah currently its returning 2 rows which is better than the 6 rows it was returning. Still working on getting it to only return 1 row per unique number

Comment: The OP has been updated for the last time with the final working example.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Script

```
;WITH CTE(number ,line ,partNum ,phoneNum     ,qty_SN ,qty_Property ,qty_Name ,qty_Time)
AS
(
SELECT 87     ,1    ,  '55G5'    ,'555-789-7512'    ,00123  ,'Local'        ,'Owner'    ,'05:22' UNION ALL
SELECT 87     ,NULL    ,NULL       ,NULL        ,14988  ,'Local'        ,'Seller'   ,'10:44' UNION ALL
SELECT 87     ,NULL    ,NULL       ,NULL        ,521    ,'Remote'       ,'Owner'    ,'01:05' UNION ALL
SELECT 87     ,NULL    ,NULL       ,NULL        ,50697  ,'Local'        ,'Seller'   ,'11:41' UNION ALL
SELECT 87     ,NULL    ,NULL       ,NULL        ,2359   ,'Remote'       ,'Seller'   ,'04:45'
)
SELECT * FROM
(              
SELECT DISTINCT  number, line,partNum ,phoneNum,
        STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(qty_SN AS Varchar(10)) FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS qty_SN,
        STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(qty_Property AS Varchar(10)) FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS qty_Property,
        STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(qty_Name AS Varchar(10)) FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS qty_Name,
        STUFF((SELECT ', '+CAST(qty_Time AS Varchar(10)) FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS qty_Time
FROM CTE
)dt
WHERE line IS NOT NULL OR partNum IS  NOT NULL OR phoneNum IS NOT NULL
```

Demo:  http://rextester.com/IUA22801

Comment: Thanks for this example, Sreenu. Using some of the things in this pointed me to the correct answer!

Comment: @StealthRT Welcom bro :)